# Load pdf images into PowerPoint

Tags: pdf, images, microsoft-powerpoint

When I import an image saved as PDF into PowerPoint the quality loss enormous. I don't want to solve it with the Snipping Tool because I remember that using Office 2013 (I think) I was able to load PDF images by simply drag and drop them without any quality loss. Now with Office 2016 it looks like that PowerPoint changes the resolution of these images.

Is there any solution?

Comment: How did you import the image from PDF to PowerPoint? The link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-pdf-file-content-into-a-powerpoint-presentation-5e7719d5-508c-4c07-a3d4-68123c373a62 shares the suggested method is to use Screen Clipping. Alternatively, you can consider to insert it as Object in PowerPoint to open it with PDF when present it.

Comment: Yes I already saw that but I remember that in the previous version of Office I could import a PDF image by simply drag and drop it from its folder.

Comment: The method suggested in the MS article mentioned above is limiting. Instead, open the PDF in Reader, use Reader's snapshot tool but first zoom in considerably. As you click and drag to select the snapshot area, Reader will scroll the scree, so the whole area you want to capture needn't be visible on screen to start (as it must be in the MS-suggested method). The more you zoom in before capturing a snapshot, the higher the resolution of the image you'll capture (and then paste into PPT)

Comment: Yes but in this way is difficult obtain images of the same size because with the snipping tool you use a mouse and when you take a snapshot you won't take picture of the same size. Never. While all my PDF images have the same size. That's why I needed to import the PDF image

Comment: It's easy enough to resize the images to whatever size you want once you've pasted them into PPT.